# Using Interceptor in EF Core not working to identify where a query is run from in application

Tags: entity-framework-core

We have queries generated by EF Core in our application that are not efficient

Whilst these queries show in Azure under long running queries etc its virtually impossible to establish where some of these queries come from

So I thought I could use an interceptor to log a GUID that would then show in Query Store

However, when I look at the query it has had its comment stripped out

I also tried to add a parameter on the fly but as this isnt used in the query it seems to get removed

Has anyone got an alternative?

The idea is that when running the query we log the ID which then goes to App Insights

From there we can use the rest of the logging to work out where in the application the query comes from

This example changes the command text to add a comment

```cs
public class MyCommandInterceptor<T> : DbCommandInterceptor
    where T : DbContext
{
    private readonly ILogger<T> _logger;
    public bool LogQueryDuration { get; set; }

    public PrivalgoQueryCommandInterceptor(ILogger<T> logger)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    private void LogExecuting(DbCommand command, string commandType)
    {
        var queryId = Guid.NewGuid();

        command.CommandText = $"--QUERYID {queryId}{Environment.NewLine}{command.CommandText}";

        _logger.LogInformation($"RunningQuery - {commandType} - {queryId}");
    }

    public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
    {
        LogExecuting(command, "Reader");
        return base.ReaderExecuting(command, eventData, result);
    }

    public override InterceptionResult<object> ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<object> result)
    {
        LogExecuting(command, "Scalar");
        return base.ScalarExecuting(command, eventData, result);
    }

    public override InterceptionResult<int> NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result)
    {
        LogExecuting(command, "NonQuery");
        return base.NonQueryExecuting(command, eventData, result);
    }

    public override async Task<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        LogExecuting(command, "Reader");
        return await base.ReaderExecutingAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override async Task<InterceptionResult<object>> ScalarExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<object> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        LogExecuting(command, "Scaler");
        return await base.ScalarExecutingAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
        
    }

    public override async Task<InterceptionResult<int>> NonQueryExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        LogExecuting(command, "NonQuery");
        return await base.NonQueryExecutingAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

The logic for adding a parameter is below

```cs
private void LogExecuting(DbCommand command, string commandType)
{
    var queryId = Guid.NewGuid();

    var parameter = new SqlParameter("@QueryId", queryId);
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

    _logger.LogInformation($"RunningQuery - {commandType} - {queryId}");
}
```

But this doesnt work either - the parameter is lost

Does anyone have any ideas?

I was wondering about query filtering but Im not sure how to use that in this context?

Paul

Comment: *comment stripped out* - which service do that? Have you added comment with `TagWith`?

Comment: When I look at a query in Query Store the comment is not shown in the SQL.  I cant see how to use TagWith for all queries?  I am using Ef Core for .NET Core 3.1

Comment: TagWith will not help if comments are removed. You need to find a way when additional information is preserved in Query Store.

Comment: Have you tried `/* Comment */ ` syntax? Add several comments.

Comment: Not really going to help with finding a solution, but in general EF does not "pass through" queries - it creates them. It makes sense that things like comments which are not needed for execution are ignored. I could easily see unused parameters also being left out of the generated sql for the same reason.